# Bash script infinite while loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, ubuntu, while-loop

I'm currently creating a personal post installation script for my ubuntu based system (new to linux). I created a bash script with this prompt asking whether or not to install a certain program but I get an infite loop saying "Please answer yes or no.". Can`t find the issue though...

I want to install program XY if input is "yes" or just end the loop and continue on with the script if "no".

```sh
while true; do
    read -p "Do you want to install programm XY?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) sudo apt install XY -y && apt install XYZ -y; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code works for me.  Which version of bash?  Are you sure you're running in bash?

Comment: I`m using Bash Version 5.0.17(1) release on Ubuntu 20.04. When I use the script in Linux Mint it works just fine.

Comment: When I run the script local on my machine it works just fine, but when I run it with "wget" from Github it creates the loop.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by running it with "wget" from Github? Could you edit your question to show exactly which code does not work?

Comment: Running with wget?  Lets assume you are downloading the script using wget.  What do you do next?  I expect you add the execute permission to the file and run it.  Complete guess here, maybe run a `dos2unix` on it before you run the script?

Comment: Thanks for your guesses so far but i was able to solve it: I changed the way the script gets executed from just "wget -O url.com/projectxy/install.sh | bash" to "wget -O - url.com/projectxy/install.sh  -v -O install.sh && sudo sh ./install.sh; rm -rf install.sh". So my script will be downloaded, executed and removed after it completed.